# c# Function to export text file only runs once

Tags: c#, function, gridview, export, text-files

I have a function to export the contents of a gridview to a text file. It works fine, but it only works once. It successfully exports the first file sent to it, but then my program just stops. I've tried  it on multiple gridviews, so I know it works, but it will only export the first grid sent to it. My HTML:

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvCTSWContracts" />
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvCTSWDischargeCurves" />
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvCTSWPrimaryDevices" />
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvCTSWStations" />
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvCTSWTaskOrders" />
```

My function:

```
public void ExportGrid(GridView gv, string gvName)
{

    //  Build the text file data
    string txt = string.Empty;

    txt += "<table id='tblCTSWContracts' border='1'>";

    //  Add the header row for text file
    txt += "<tr>";
    foreach (TableCell cell in gv.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        txt += "<th>";        
        txt += cell.Text + "\t\t";
        txt += "</th>";
    }
    txt += "</tr>";

    //  Add header line
    txt += "\r\n";

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        //  Add the Data rows            
        txt += "<tr>";
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            txt += "<td>";
            txt += cell.Text + "\t\t";
            txt += "</td>";
        }
        txt += "</tr>";
        //  Add new line    
        txt += "\r\n";    
    }

    txt += "<table>";

    //  Export the file
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + gvName + ".html");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.Output.Write(txt);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

}
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
protected void ExportAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportGrid(gvCTSWContracts, "CTSWContracts");
    ExportGrid(gvCTSWDischargeCurves, "CTSWDischargeCurves");
    ExportGrid(gvCTSWPrimaryDevices, "CTSWPrimaryDevices");
    ExportGrid(gvCTSWStations, "CTSWStations");
    ExportGrid(gvCTSWTaskOrders, "CTSWTaskOrders");
}
```

Can anyone tell me why all of my grids aren't being exported as separate files? Thank you.

Comment: Think you need to look up what  [Response.End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524629(v=vs.90)) does.. And then change your export so it returns a string, collect all the strings and send them once

Comment: First of all, `Response.End` will literally end the output, it literally aborts the thread. Secondly, you cannot send multiple files in a single HTTP request.